# Why do systemd-nspawn's network namespaces not work correctly without systemd running inside the container?

Tags: networking, systemd, container, systemd-nspawn

I am trying to run a systemd-nspawn container without an init system and inside of a systemd-nspawn-managed network namespace. My container is a stock Fedora 35 image, and I am invoking it like so:

```bsh
systemd-nspawn --network-bridge=virbr0 --port 5555:9001 --directory=/container/f35 python3 -m http.server 9001
```

My intention is to privately isolate the network of the container such that I'd use the bridge's IP address and port 5555 to access the web server running at port 9001 inside of the container. However, when I try to connect to the container, it fails immediately. When I view `ip link` on the host, I get the following relevant output:

```
3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:10:6d:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
39: vb-f35@if2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state LOWERLAYERDOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:67:2d:18:5e:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
```

I noticed that NO-CARRIER is listed for both `virbr0 and vb-f35@if2`. When I change the container to `--boot` instead of running the web server as its command, `ip link` shows the following for the relevant interfaces:

```
3: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:10:6d:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
40: vb-f35@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:67:2d:18:5e:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
```

And I can successfully ping a web server I then run at port 9001 inside of the container from the outside world.

Obviously systemd inside of the container is doing something to initialize the networking correctly, but I'm having trouble figuring out what exactly. Does anyone have any advice for determining what that is? Or if there are tips out there on how to get systemd-nspawn to set up the networking itself without relying on systemd inside of the container to do something, that'd be fantastic.

Edit:

I am providing the information A.B. requested in a comment below this question.

Output of `iptables-save -c` before starting my container:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [332:41133]
:INPUT ACCEPT [291:39665]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7041:549405]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7041:549405]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
[7043:549565] -A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
[7:513] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[1:84] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [117102:151146445]
:INPUT ACCEPT [117086:151145517]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [6:504]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [64309:5329802]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [64357:5334100]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
[64366:5334974] -A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
[6:1968] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [117205:151170716]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [64424:5339032]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [117138:151166535]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [6:504]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [64424:5339032]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:43:20 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [117077:151143379]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [64305:5327950]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
[117096:151152501] -A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
[6:504] -A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
[6:504] -A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
[3:252] -A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
[64323:5331044] -A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
[3:252] -A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[3:252] -A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[3:218] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[6:1920] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[6:1968] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Output of `iptables-save -c` after creating the container:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [374:46301]
:INPUT ACCEPT [329:44705]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [7315:580228]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7315:580228]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
[7317:580388] -A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
[8:580] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
[1:84] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [130977:169443079]
:INPUT ACCEPT [130961:169442151]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [6:504]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [70277:5768739]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [70327:5773171]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
[70336:5774045] -A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
[6:1968] -A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [131080:169467350]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [70392:5777969]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
*security
:INPUT ACCEPT [131008:169462974]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [6:504]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [70392:5777969]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [130952:169440013]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [70273:5766887]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
[130971:169449135] -A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
[6:504] -A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
[6:504] -A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
[3:252] -A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
[70291:5769981] -A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
[3:252] -A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[3:252] -A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
[3:218] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[6:1920] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
[6:1968] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
[0:0] -A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Mar 13 13:47:31 2022
```

The entirety of `ip link; ip -br address; ip route` on the host:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:31:bf:51:06:fd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:10:6d:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: vb-f35@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master virbr0 state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ba:67:2d:18:5e:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
enp3s0           UP             192.168.1.197/24 fe80::7508:4c69:8ad8:166c/64
virbr0           UP             192.168.122.1/24
vb-f35@if2       UP             fe80::b867:2dff:fe18:5e8f/64
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp3s0 proto dhcp metric 100
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp3s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.197 metric 100
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

Comment: The bridge here, despite its name and function, should be used to *route* to the container, not to bridge to it. It would be used as an actual bridge only if the host's main interface was also set as bridge port, but there's no such information shown in OP. One interface isn't shown in OP: the container's other side of the veth pair (the peer of vb-f35). That's the one causing NO-CARRIER because it can't be configured by the web server. As your intent is unclear,you should check these pieces of documentation: https://manpages.debian.org/veth.4 , https://manpages.debian.org/network_namespaces.7

Comment: Thanks for the info. If I instead run a shell inside of my container, I see the container-side peer as host0@if42. If I run `ip link set host0 up` inside of the container, it does transition to the "up" state both inside and outside of the container, but I still can't route to the container on the bridge's ip address, so it looks like there's more setup that needs to happen inside the container?

Comment: I can't give much more because even the ping in the question might have been a ping to the host rather than the container without seeing the whole layout.  You appear, from its name, to be reusing an interface created with libvirt (eg: I expect later to see the address 192.168.122.1 on virbr0, but this might not be libvirt at all either) . You should provide all of this: `iptables-save -c` before the setup, the after the setup again `iptables-save -c` and also: `ip link; ip -br address; ip route`. This would clarify the configuration.

Comment: I have edited in the requested info to the OP - if something isn't quite right I am happy to provide more information. I am a bit out of my depth here, as you maybe can tell. I am able to manually configure a network namespace myself that accomplishes what I want, but I can't figure out why I can't get nspawn to do so (and my debugging skills are poor in this area)

Comment: I don't know how to get the --port option to work properly, so I can't give an answer to this question. I can just tell that the network namespace has to be configured in a compatible manner with the rest of the network: with host0 given an address such as 192.168.122.2/24 and a default route via 192.168.122.1 . Normally this should be done using DHCP and not manually. You'd better keep using the --boot option if it does this automatically.